# Add multiple sheets, name them, and copy paste dynamic range into new sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to excel and I'm trying to add multiple sheets, name each one. The macro is only adding one sheet at a time, example I will click "run" and it will create the "Price Adjustment" table but no others.  When I click "run" again it will create the following table only, and so on.

```
Sub NewSheets()

With Sheets.Add()
    .Name = "CustomerTable"
    .Name = "EmployeeTable"
    .Name = "OrdersTable"
    .Name = "ProductTable"
    .Name = "PriceAdjustment"
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The quickest improvement of the code is to move `Add() method` inside `With...End With` statement like this:

```
Sub NewSheets()

With Sheets
    .Add().Name = "CustomerTable"
    .Add().Name = "EmployeeTable"
    .Add().Name = "OrdersTable"
    .Add().Name = "ProductTable"
    .Add().Name = "PriceAdjustment"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this is to put the new sheet names into an array and then loop through the array to create all five of your tables at once.

Couple of things to note about the code:

- The array `shArray` for the sheet names is declared as a Variant so that we can populate the array with the `Array` function without having to loop through the array to assign each element.
- In setting up the `For` loop, I use the `LBound` and `UBound` functions to calculate the index numbers for the first and last elements of the array. That way, it's not necessary to keep track of the number of array elements if the number changes.

  ```
  Option Explicit                        'Turn on compiler option requiring
                                         'that all variables be declared
  Sub NewSheets()

    Dim shArray() As Variant             'Declare the sheet Name array and a
    Dim i As Long                        'counter variable

    shArray = Array("CustomerTable", _
                    "EmployeeTable", _
                    "OrdersTable", _
                    "ProductTable", _
                    "PriceAdjustment")   'Populate the array

    For i = LBound(shArray) To UBound(shArray)  'Loop through the elements
        Sheets.Add().Name = shArray(i)           
    Next i

  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling the `Add()` method once. Try this:

```
Sub AddNewWorksheet(name as String)
    With Worksheets.Add()
        .Name = name
    End With
End Sub
```

Then you can add worksheets just like this:

```
AddNewWorksheet("CustomerTable")
AddNewWorksheet("EmployeeTable")
'...
```